# Joining two Char*

Tags: c++

I have the below statement , what I want to do is set the variable message to equal itself plus data
 message = message + data

How would I do this ? i'm still very new to C++

```
void DataLog::log(char* data)
 {
struct sockaddr_in si_other;
    int s, slen=sizeof(si_other);
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    char* message;
    WSADATA wsa;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you know about [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) and [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat)?

Comment: C++ does not require `struct ` before declaring a struct variable.

Comment: By the way, if the data contains binary data (and therefore can contain the value `0` (the C/C++ string terminator character) in the middle of the data) you might want to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: "How do I concatenate two C-strings" is what you wanted to ask. Plenty of information already exists about how to do this.

Comment: There's also `std::string`, which doesn't care about `0` either. (Of course, do pass the length of a string when it has embedded zeroes.

Answer (score 4):

[strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/)
is way to go.

But, as you are working with c++ better use `std::string` instead of `char*`

with `std::string` you can simply add two `strings` with `+` operator.

Comment: Unless the data is binary as @Joachim points out then a `std::vector` would be better.

Comment: @graham.reeds: There's no problem storing binary data in `std::string`; and it's more convenient than `vector` if you want to do stringy operations like concatenation. (Obviously, you couldn't use `strcat` with arbitrary binary data, but you wouldn't use that in C++ anyway. And `vector` might be more convenient to write into.)

Comment: @graham.reeds Mike yes we have these options open for binary data... but seems OP is not bothered about it.. std::string might suffice his need. thanks both of you for info :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this would be one way to do it:

```
void DataLog::log(char* data)
 {
    ...
    std::string message (buf); //or whatever you use to initialize the message
    message.append (data); //the second part of the message
}
```